# Are random updates disk bound mostly in standard and append only databases?

Tags: algorithm, database-design, data-structures

If I have large dataset and do random updates then I think updates are mostly disk bounded (in case append only databases there is not about seeks but about bandwidth I think). When I update record slightly one data page must be updated, so if my disk can write 10MB/s of data and page size is 16KB then i can have max 640 random updates per second. In append only databases apout 320 per second bacause one update can take two pages - index and data. In other databases bacause of ranom seeks to update page in place can be even worse like 100 updates per second.

I assume that one page in cache has only one update before write (random updates). Going forward the same will by for random inserts around all data pages (for examle not time ordered UUID) or even worst.

I refer to the situation when dirty pages (after update) must be flushed to disk and synced (can't longer stay in cache). So updates per second count is in this situation disk bandwidth bounded? Are my calculations like 320 updates per second likely? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: "update record ... one data page" and "append ... can take two pages: index and data".  Why doesn't update alter the index?  Are  you assuming all rows are of identical size?  No row will ever move because it got larger?

Comment: These are only general and optimistic (at update in place) assumptions, I think random updates per second can only be worse for presented situation. Maybe there is something tricky (except cache) that I do not know? Am I thinking right?

Comment: Your thinking is along the right path.  Details will depend on your exact system.  (For an important instance if you stripe data across many hard drives, you can be much faster.)

Comment: "so if my disk can write 10MB/s of data and page size is 16KB then i can have max 640 random updates per second." - Nope. Doesn't quite scale that way. Max will be much lower. sequentially writing data at 10MB/s does not directly translate into the numbers you assumed for random writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It depends."

To be complete, there are other things to consider.

First, the only thing distinguishing a random update from an append is the head seek involved. A random update will have the head dancing all over the platter, whereas an append will ideally just track like record player. This also assumes that each disk write is the full write and completely independent of all other writes.

Of course, that's in a perfect world.

With most modern databases, each update will typically involve, at a minimum, 2 writes. One for the actual data, the other for the log.

In a typical scenario, if you update a row, the database will make the change in memory. If you commit that row, the database will acknowledge that by making a note in the log, while keeping the actual dirty page in memory. Later, when the database checkpoints it will right the dirty pages to the disk. But when it does this, it will sort the blocks and write them as sequentially as it can. Then it will write a checkpoint to the log.

During recovery when the DB crashed and could not checkpoint, the database reads the log up to the last checkpoint, "rolls it forward" and applies those changes to actual disk page, marks the final checkpoint, then makes the system available for service.

The log write is sequential, the data writes are mostly sequential.

Now, if the log is part of a normal file (typical today) then you write the log record, which appends to the disk file. The FILE SYSTEM will then (likely) append to ITS log that change you just made so that it can update it's local file system structures. Later, the file system will, also, commit its dirty pages and make it's meta data changes permanent.

So, you can see that even a simple append can invoke multiple writes to the disk.

Now consider an "append only" design like CouchDB. What Couch will do, is when you make a simple write, it does not have a log. The file is its own log. Couch DB files grow without end, and need compaction during maintenance. But when it does the write, it writes not just the data page, but any indexes affected. And when indexes are affected, then Couch will rewrite the entire BRANCH of the index change from root to leaf. So, a simple write in this case can be more expensive than you would first think.

Now, of course, you throw in all of the random reads to disrupt your random writes and it all get quite complicated quite quickly. What I've learned though is that while streaming bandwidth is an important aspect of IO operations, overall operations per second are even more important. You can have 2 disks with the same bandwidth, but the one with the slower platter and/or head speed will have fewer ops/sec, just from head travel time and platter seek time.

Ideally, your DB uses dedicated raw storage vs a file system for storage, but most do not do that today. The advantages of file systems based stores operationally typically outweigh the performance benefits.

If you're on a file system, then preallocated, sequential files are a benefit so that your "append only" isn't simply skipping around other files on the file system, thus becoming similar to random updates. Also, by using preallocated files, your updates are simply updating DB data structures during writes rather than DB AND file system data structures as the file expands.

Putting logs, indexes, and data on separate disks allow multiple drives to work simultaneously with less interference. Your log can truly be append only for example compared to fighting with the random data reads or index updates.

So, all of those things factor in to throughput on DBs.

Comment: you're right there are many factors which depend on the measurements, I was not sure whether such databases do something tricky (like in architecture BigTable databases)